# mySQL- show nearest stores with no range or limit

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have got a very basic store locator script. which the user enters  postcode/zip-code that is converted to lat and long and then searched in the database to find the nearest stores.

my current SQL:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 500
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 100;
```

As you can see this does work, but its limited to a range of 500 miles, i want to remove the limit.  if i try remove `HAVING distance < 500` , the distance is returned as `NULL`.

I need the results to says `Store name XX miles away`.

Another question, can this query be optimized? i have lat and long cols in the database as index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance is `NULL` because some of your records have NULL values for `lat` and/or `lng`.  You can add:

```
HAVING distance is not null
```

until you fix the problem.

If you want to optimize the query, then think about using the geospatial extensions (the documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can Query :

```
// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: That's a doubled line at the end there, `$result = mysql_query($query);`, no?

Comment: sorry it was one of confusion!